# De-macro script not working anymore?

Tags: texlive, scripts

I would like to use a script which is included in TeX Live called De-macro ([link](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/support/de-macro)), this module is a bit old, the last update is from 2007 and it works with Python 2.7 I guess.

I tried to use it yesterday, so I followed the instructions :

- I created a file with some tex using macros called `ideas.tex`.
- I included `\usepackage{rmsmacros-private}` in this file.
- I created a file called `rmsmacros-private.sty` with my macros.
- Then I used the script and I did `de-macro ideas.tex`
- The script told me that all is ok and created `ideas.db` and `ideas-clean.tex`
- All seemed to be okay.

But finally, when I opened `ideas-clean.tex` which should had all my macros expanded, finally just the line `\usepackage{rmsmacros-private}` has been erased and nothing else had been changed.

So do someone has this script working or does this script not working anymore?

Thank you in advance for your help.

My code is available here : https://we.tl/t-gT3UMxOfyu

Comment: When I try to run `de-macro`, I get a syntax error (most likely it was written for Python2 and fails on Python3, will not look into it).

Comment: de-macro seems to work fine for me... could you post your code? (system python 2.7.10 on macOS 10.13)

Comment: Also works for me.  Remember to clean out intermediate files between testing, in particular the `.db` file.

Comment: I edited my post with a link where you can download my  code. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You used `\def`s in you `.sty` file, which are not compatible with `de-macro`. From its documentation: "Only newcommand, renewcommand, newenvironment, and renewenvironment are understood"

Comment: I would suggest to replace the `\def` with the fresher `\newcommand`, for most of your commands it should be straight forward. Also, maybe you could just copy-paste the code from `.sty` into the header of your `.tex`, if you want to make your file portable?

Comment: Thank you so much Peater. Does the script take care of macros write on the header of the file ?

Comment: not always... commands without argument, like `\ker` etc work. `\def\ep#1` could be replaced with `\newcommand\ep[1]`, and `\def\drp#1#2` with `\newcommand\drp[2]`. `\def` overwrites all previous definitions, so for e.g. `\Im` which already exist in latex, you would need something like `\renewcommand`. Note that `\newtheorem` would also be ignored by `de-macro`, no chance.

Comment: If you copy-paste your entire `.sty` into the header of the `.tex`, you do not need the script any more  What is your motivation for using `de-macro`?

Comment: Ok I understand, thank you for your help Peater. Do I have to put somewhere that my problem is solved ?

Comment: Hum I have a system where I need to be able to fork a question write in latex between users, and to do this I need to use latex without macro because macro are proper to users and so cannot be shared.

Comment: Interesting... What exactly do you mean by "without macros" — basically everything is a macro, also `\mathbb`, etc... You do not need to put your "user macros" in an extra `.sty` file, neither in the header section... You could just copy your `\def...` line directly in your comment?

Comment: @EvanBarberousse I think you cannot accept your own answer 

Comment: In my system only the question is saved is database, all others info like package and Macros are saved in another file  which is external from the question. And when you fork the question, I only fork the question itself, not all the tex file. And yes I cannot accept , but for people who join they can see the response easily without reading everything ^^

Comment: as you can write LaTeX in your forked question, what prevents you from doing something like `\def\eclaire{\mathbb} \def\R{\ensuremath{\eclaire R}}Existe-t-il une suite dans $\R$`?

Comment: @EvanBarberousse I added an answer too, which you could accept if you feel like 

Comment: Hi @PeaterdeXel, I feel a bit disappointed today because I tried what you said and I raise a new error, I just tried a very basic example: Here is my code https://we.tl/t-vIpjGGky6q. My error is : TypeError: exceptions must be old-style classes or derived from BaseException, not str
Seems to be a python error...

Comment: NB: the `\everymath\displaystyle` and `\DeclareMathSymbol` would get lost when you use `de-macro`. It *only* takes the command/environment definitions... So I think there is no way around putting some things into the main file / the code you upload. I'll look into the exception.

Comment: **TeX:** The error comes from the fact that you wrote `\usepackage{rmsmacros-private}`, but the package is called `testmacro-private.sty`, so `de-macro` does not find your definitions. Rename your file!
**python:** The code seems to be written for python 2.5, and thus raises a string as an exception, which was removed from python 2.6+. But as long as there is no exception is to be raised, you are good with python 2.7...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation of `de-macro` states that

> Only newcommand, renewcommand, newenvironment, and renewenvironment are understood

As you use `\def` in your `.sty`-file, `de-macro` does not work like you expected. I would suggest to either

- replace `\def` with the newer `\newcommand`, if you want to continue using `de-macro`
- put your own definitions directly into the main file, and skip `de-macro`.

---

**Syntax Error**

Note that `de-macro` requires python 2, so if you get a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`, your `/usr/bin/python` is most likely version 3.

A quick and dirty fix would be to change the first line of the `de-macro`-script from

```
#!/usr/bin/python -O
```

to

```
#!/usr/bin/python2 -O
```

You can find the location of the `de-macro`-script with `which de-macro` — on my Mac it's `/Library/TeX/texbin/de-macro`.

Comment: Thanks, just found that `de-macro` is no more part of TeX Live. I downloaded the latest version from `https://ctan.org/pkg/de-macro`, which was luckily made compatible with Python 2.7 and 3. However, under Ubuntu 20.04, I had to manually install it, i.e. to copy the altered Python file calling `python3` into `/usr/bin`.