# Is there a way to convert \def macro in \newcommand macro automatically?

Tags: macros, scripts

I have a big file of macros, they are all in this form :

```
\def\eclaire{\mathbb}
\def\R{\ensuremath{\eclaire R}}
```

I want to have them in `\newcommand` form, for those macro it's quite easy, i just have to replace `\def` by `\newcommand` like this :

```
\newcommand \eclaire{\mathbb}
\newcommand \R{\ensuremath{\eclaire R}}
```

But for some others macros like this one :

```
\def\rond#1{\build#1_{}^{\>\circ}}
```

I can't because the solution is :

```
\newcommand\rond[1]{\build#1_{}^{\>\circ}}
```

So my question is, is there a script that can transform my `\def` command into `\newcommand` automatically ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Your `\newcommand` for the `\rond` is wrong, I just corrected it. Also, `\def` and `\newcommand`, not `/def` and `/newcommand`.

Comment: I'm afraid there are no scripts which can convert `\def` to `\newcommand` _generally_. For example `\def\hello person #1 and person #2 {Hello you #1 and #2}`, it is very difficult to convert this to `\newcommand`. However, with `\def#1#2#3#4` for example, I think there are (though I don't know of).

Comment: The regexp `s/\\def(\\[^{#]*)(#[0-9])*/\\newcommand{$1}[0$2]/g` might work for `\def`s of the form `\def\<cmd>#1#2...#9` (at least it seemed to when tested against https://regexr.com/). The result is not the prettiest for parameterless macros, because it produces `\newcommand{\foo}[0]{...}` instead of `\newcommand{\foo}{...}`, but that should be acceptable.

Comment: I forgot to ignore the `#` in the second group and you may want to catch things like `\def\foo##1` as well. So `\\def(\\[^{#]*)(?:#+([0-9]))*` would probably be better.

Comment: I am going to make some tests to see if it works correctly, thank you :)

Comment: I have tested on this file https://we.tl/t-SEbGo9QWps, and nearly all work correctly. Thank you @moewe, you could put your solution as the good answer ;)

Comment: @EvanBarberousse But, after all, **why do you want to convert `\def` to `\newcommand`?**

Comment: Possibly relevant for the motivation: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/475311/35864

Comment: Exactly my motivation @moewe

Comment: Be aware that in terms of `\def` you can define macros that process delimited arguments while you can't do this in terms of `\newcommand`. Therefore you cannot convert each `\def` into a `\newcommand`.

Comment: @UlrichDiez Poor man's workaround: `\newcommand{\foo}{}\def\foo funny{...}`

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek We both know that with this workaround `\foo` will be (re)defined in any case while with `\@ifdefinable\foo{\def\foo funny{...}}` `\foo` will be defined only if `\foo` is undefined. ;-)

Comment: @UlrichDiez We also both know that the category code of `@` matters, in the preamble, something like `\makeatletter\@ifdefinable\foo{...}\makeatother` then helps. But, is this still "poor"? ;-)

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek When I wrote my last comment, I had a little problem: On the one hand, it is directly related to your last comment. That is why it is a reply to your comment. On the other hand, I also intended to express that I don't think that someone with your skills needs to get explained the things I explained, but that the target group is people who just begin thinking about the subtle differences between similar snippets of code related to the same problem. Seems my attempt at putting this into words failed, and therefore my comment can be interpreted differently. I apologize.

Comment: @UlrichDiez \relax and Merry Christmas, we have both used smileys in our comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\def` and `\newcommand` are not fully equivalent, since `\newcommand` will throw an error if it is asked to redefine an existing command. `\newcommand` is therefore preferred if you want to define new commands, but it can not be used to redefine existing commands. This is not something a script can easily detect, so I will ignore it for now, even if it is relevant to your intended use case, where you have, for example

```
\newenvironment{Cases}{%
  \left\lbrace
  \def\arraystretch{1.2}%
  \array{@{}l@{\quad}l@{}}
}{%
  \endarray\right.%
}
```

Furthermore, `\def` and `\newcommand` don't support exactly the same syntax definitions. `\newcommand` can only define macros with up to nine (mandatory) arguments, where the first argument may be optional (and wrapped in square brackets instead). `\def` can also support other delimited macros. I will assume that your `\def`s are only of the form `\def\<cmd>{...}` or `\def\<cmd>#1...#n`. This was already mentioned by [JouleV](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/156344/joulev) [in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/481029/is-there-a-way-to-convert-def-macro-in-newcommand-macro-automatically?noredirect=1#comment1215570_481029). This is an issue for

```
\def\build#1_#2^#3{\mathrel{\mathop{\kern 0pt#1}\limits_{#2}^{#3}}} %CLENET
```

`\newcommand` also does not allow for prefixes like `\long`, `\outer`, `\protected`. So if you use those you can't easily switch to `\newcommand`, either. (Except maybe for `\long`/not `\long` which is mapped to `\newcommand`/`\newcommand*`.) I will assume you use none of those prefixes and I will use `\newcommand`, which makes its arguments `\long`, but you could of course use `\newcommand*` to get "un`\long`" arguments.

If we allow for these simplifications

```
s/\\def(\\[^{#]*)(?:#+([0-9]))*{/\\newcommand{$1}[0$2]{/g
```

yields acceptable results.

The following (crude approximation of a) Lua script does something quite similar. I didn't manage to get the matching for the argument structure `#1`, `#1#2`, ... done in a single group, so I opted for a loop doing that instead.

```lua
local io = require('io')
local string = string

local filename = arg[1] or nil

function newcommandify(content)
  content = string.gsub(content, "\\def(\\[^{#]*){",
                        "\\newcommand{%1}{")
  local iargs = ''
  for i=1,9 do
    iargs = iargs .. "#+" .. i
    content = string.gsub(content, "\\def(\\[^{#]*)" .. iargs .. "{",
                          "\\newcommand{%1}[".. i .. "]{")
  end
  return content
end

if filename then
  local file_handle = assert(io.open(filename, 'r'))
  local content = file_handle:read('*all')
  io.close(file_handle)

  content = newcommandify(content)

  file_handle = assert(io.open(filename .. "-newcommand", 'w'))
  file_handle:write(content)
  io.close(file_handle)
end
```

Save it as `def-to-newcommand.lua` and run

```
texlua def-to-newcommand.lua <yourfilename>
```

to obtain `<yourfilename>-newcommand` with `\def`s converted to `\newcommand`.

Comment: the LUA script do not work for this `
\def{\Sp}{\mathop{\rm Sp}\nolimits}
\def{\spec}{\mathop{\rm sp}\nolimits}` Do you know why ?

Comment: @EvanBarberousse It doesn't catch those. You can catch them by additionally searching for `"\\def{(\\[^{#]*)}{"` and `"\\def{(\\[^{#]*)}" .. iargs .. "{"`.

Comment: `\def{\Sp}` is bad syntax for `\def`.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you wish to transform assignments in terms of `\def` into assignments in terms of `\newcommand`?

If it is only about ensuring that macros that are already defined won't get overridden, you can do another approach:

Basically `\newcommand` behaves as follows:

It checks for a star and optional argument and applies the kernel-macro `\@ifdefinable` for finding out whether the control sequence token in question is already defined within the current scope.

If so, `\@ifdefinable` will throw an error-message and not (re)define the control sequence token in question.

If not so, the control-sequence-token in question will be defined in terms of `\def` (, probably preceded by `\long`). In case of processing optional arguments, routines for detecting the presence of an optional argument will be included into the definitions performed by `\newcommand`, also.

Caveats with `\newcommand`:

- `\newcommand` itself is a macro/is a "mechanism" which is based on macros. If the arguments of macros contain tokens that are defined in terms of `\outer`, (La)TeX will deliver an error-message. Thus: If you try to define a command via `\newcommand` which is already defined in terms of `\outer`, you will not get the error-message about the control-sequence already being defined but you will get an error-message `! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of \new@command.`
- `\newcommand` will check for the command being already defined only within the current scope. If not, it will define that command only within the current scope. Therefore the check of `\newcommand` is not completely safe when intending to define a macro globally, e.g., via `\newcommand\foo{bar}\global\let\foo=\foo`.
- Actually the `\newcommand`-"mechanism" does not check for the command being already defined, but it checks whether the command is already defined to something other than the meaning of the `\relax` primitive. It does so by applying `\csname..\endcsname` to the name of the command (which is formed by applying `\string` and removing the leading backslash) and then via `\ifx` checking whether the meaning of the command equals the meaning of the `\relax`-primitive. It does so because `\csname..\endcsname` itself does (regardless the value of the `\globaldefs`-parameter) (only) within the current scope assign the meaning of the `\relax`-primitive to the tokens it forms in case they are undefined at the time of forming them. Therefore `\newcommand` silently redefines control-sequence-tokens that are already defined and whose meaning equals the `\relax`-primitive. E.g., you can do

  ```
  \let\MyCommand=\relax
  % now \MyCommand is defined and its meaning equals the meaning of the \relax-primitive
  \newcommand\MyCommand{This is the redefinition of MyCommand which gets carried out without warnings/error-messages.}
  ```

  You can also do this within a local scope/within a group for causing `\newcommand` to take `\MyCommand` for undefined within that scope.

  A caveat is: If you do something like

  ```
  \begingroup
  \let\MyCommand=\relax
  % now \MyCommand is defined and its meaning equals the meaning of the \relax-primitive
  \newcommand\MyCommand{This is the redefinition of MyCommand which gets carried out without warnings/error-messages.}
  \global\let\MyCommand=\MyCommand
  \endgroup
  ```

  , `\MyCommand` might already have been defined outside the group and it will be overridden outside the group/within all scopes without whatsoever notification.

My suggested approach is:

Assignments in terms of `\def` are always of pattern

`⟨prefix⟩\def⟨control sequence token⟩⟨parameter text⟩{⟨replacement text⟩}`

, with *⟨prefix⟩* =emptiness or a combination of `\global` and/or `\long` and/or `\outer`.

(With `\gdef` or `\edef` or `\xdef`  the pattern looks accordingly.)

You can implement a macro `\definedchecker` which via catching a left-brace-delimited argument (→see the TeXbook for `#1#{`-notation) gathers the *⟨prefix⟩*, the `\def`, the *⟨control sequence token⟩* and the *⟨parameter text⟩* and then checks whether this contains `\def` or `\gdef` or `\edef` or `\xdef` and if so uses that information for splitting the *⟨prefix⟩*, the `\def`, the *⟨control sequence token⟩* and the *⟨parameter text⟩* apart before applying `\@ifdefinable`—but be aware that the `\@ifdefinable`-check is not completely save when it is about defining a control sequence token not only within the current scope but globally.

In other words: You can implement a macro `\definedchecker` which is to be prepended to your `\def`/`\gdef`/`\edef`/`\xdef`-sequences and which checks whether the control sequence token in question is already defined **within the current scope** and if so delivers an error-message and if not so performs the assignment.
!!!Be aware that checking for a control sequence token being defined within the current scope is not completely safe when it comes to defining it globally!!!

```
% Compile this example by calling LaTeX from a shell/command-prompt/console
% where you can also see the messages of the program!
%
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
%%<-------------------------------------------------------------------->
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%......................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\expandafter\@firstoftwo{ }{}%
  \@secondoftwo}{\expandafter\expandafter\@firstoftwo{ }{}\@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%<-------------------------------------------------------------------->
%% Code for definedchecker
%%......................................................................     
\@ifdefinable\UD@gobbleto@def{\long\def\UD@gobbleto@def#1\def{}}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@gobbleto@gdef{\long\def\UD@gobbleto@gdef#1\gdef{}}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@gobbleto@edef{\long\def\UD@gobbleto@edef#1\edef{}}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@gobbleto@xdef{\long\def\UD@gobbleto@xdef#1\xdef{}}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNoDef[1]{\expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@gobbleto@def#1\def}}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNoGdef[1]{\expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@gobbleto@gdef#1\gdef}}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNoEdef[1]{\expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@gobbleto@edef#1\edef}}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNoXdef[1]{\expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@gobbleto@xdef#1\xdef}}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@catchto@gef{\long\def\UD@catch@def#1\def#2#3#{\innerdefinedchecker{#1}{\def}{#2}{#3}}}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@catchto@gdef{\long\def\UD@catch@gdef#1\gdef#2#3#{\innerdefinedchecker{#1}{\gdef}{#2}{#3}}}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@catchto@edef{\long\def\UD@catch@edef#1\edef#2#3#{\innerdefinedchecker{#1}{\edef}{#2}{#3}}}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@catchto@xdef{\long\def\UD@catch@xdef#1\xdef#2#3#{\innerdefinedchecker{#1}{\xdef}{#2}{#3}}}%
\newcommand\innerdefinedchecker[5]{\@ifdefinable{#3}{#1#2#3#4{#5}}}%
\@ifdefinable\definedchecker{%
  \long\def\definedchecker#1#{%
     \UD@CheckWhetherNoDef{#1}{%
       \UD@CheckWhetherNoGdef{#1}{%
         \UD@CheckWhetherNoEdef{#1}{%
           \UD@CheckWhetherNoXdef{#1}{%
             #1%
           }{\UD@catch@xdef#1}%
         }{\UD@catch@edef#1}%
       }{\UD@catch@gdef#1}%
     }{\UD@catch@def#1}%
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\definedchecker\xdef\eclaire{\noexpand\mathbb}
\show\eclaire

\definedchecker\def\R{\ensuremath{\eclaire R}}
\show\R

\definedchecker\outer\global\long\def\myWeirdCommand#1Delimier#2delimiter#{This is my weird command}
\show\myWeirdCommand

% These throw "command already defined"-errors and leave the previous meanings untouched:

\definedchecker\edef\eclaire{Weird Redefinition of eclaire}
\show\eclaire

\definedchecker\gdef\R{Weird Redefinition of R}
\show\R

% Don't do this as \myWeirdCommand is outer.
% \newcommand\myWeirdCommand{Blah}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Here are the messages that I get into **test.log** when saving this as **test.tex** and compiling with pdflatex:

```
> \eclaire=macro:
->\mathbb .
l.111     \show\eclaire

? 
> \R=macro:
->\ensuremath {\eclaire R}.
l.114     \show\R

? 
> \myWeirdCommand=\long\outer macro:
#1Delimier#2delimiter{->This is my weird command{.
l.117     \show\myWeirdCommand

? 

! LaTeX Error: Command \eclaire already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.121 ...ef\eclaire{Weird Redefinition of eclaire}

? 
> \eclaire=macro:
->\mathbb .
l.122     \show\eclaire

? 

! LaTeX Error: Command \R already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.124 ...edchecker\gdef\R{Weird Redefinition of R}

? 
> \R=macro:
->\ensuremath {\eclaire R}.
l.125     \show\R
```

From these messages you can see:

In case the command in question within the current scope is already defined to have a meaning other the meaning of the `\relax`-primitive, `\definedchecker` delivers an error and does not carry out the assignment.
Otherwise the assignment is carried out.

Be aware that, regarding avoiding overriding definitions of macros that are already defined, this strategy is not completely safe when it comes to defining macros globally.

Answer (score 2):

A Python program `def_to_newcommand.py`:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse
import re


def main():
    args = parse_command_line()
    data = read(args.input)
    data = convert(data)
    write(args.output, data)


def parse_command_line():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Replace \\def with \\newcommand where possible.',
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        'input',
        help='TeX input file with \\def',
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '--output',
        '-o',
        required=True,
        help='TeX output file with \\newcommand',
    )

    return parser.parse_args()


def read(path):
    with open(path, mode='rb') as handle:
        return handle.read()


def convert(data):
    return re.sub(
        rb'((?:\\(?:expandafter|global|long|outer|protected)'
        rb'(?: +|\r?\n *)?)*)?'
        rb'\\def *(\\[a-zA-Z]+) *(?:#+([0-9]))*\{',
        replace,
        data,
    )


def replace(match):
    prefix = match.group(1)
    if (
            prefix is not None and
            (
                b'expandafter' in prefix or
                b'global' in prefix or
                b'outer' in prefix or
                b'protected' in prefix
            )
    ):
        return match.group(0)

    result = rb'\newcommand'
    if prefix is None or b'long' not in prefix:
        result += b'*'

    result += b'{' + match.group(2) + b'}'
    if match.lastindex == 3:
        result += b'[' + match.group(3) + b']'

    result += b'{'
    return result


def write(path, data):
    with open(path, mode='wb') as handle:
        handle.write(data)

    print('=> File written: {0}'.format(path))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Usage example:

```bash
python3 def_to_newcommand.py foo.tex --output foo_changed.tex
```

The following definitions

```latex
\def\eclaire{\mathbb}
\def\R{\ensuremath{\eclaire R}}
\def\rond#1{\build#1_{}^{\>\circ}}
\def\build#1#2#3{\mathrel{\mathop{\kern 0pt#1}\limits_{#2}^{#3}}}
\def\build#1_#2^#3{\mathrel{\mathop{\kern 0pt#1}\limits_{#2}^{#3}}}

\long\def\eclaire{\mathbb}
\long\def\R{\ensuremath{\eclaire R}}
\long\def\rond#1{\build#1_{}^{\>\circ}}
\long\def\build#1#2#3{\mathrel{\mathop{\kern 0pt#1}\limits_{#2}^{#3}}}
\long\def\build#1_#2^#3{\mathrel{\mathop{\kern 0pt#1}\limits_{#2}^{#3}}}

\global\long\def\eclaire{\mathbb}
\global\def\eclaire{\mathbb}
\protected\def\eclaire{\mathbb}

  \long
  \def \eclaire {\mathbb}
```

are converted to:

```
\newcommand*{\eclaire}{\mathbb}
\newcommand*{\R}{\ensuremath{\eclaire R}}
\newcommand*{\rond}[1]{\build#1_{}^{\>\circ}}
\newcommand*{\build}[3]{\mathrel{\mathop{\kern 0pt#1}\limits_{#2}^{#3}}}
\def\build#1_#2^#3{\mathrel{\mathop{\kern 0pt#1}\limits_{#2}^{#3}}}

\newcommand{\eclaire}{\mathbb}
\newcommand{\R}{\ensuremath{\eclaire R}}
\newcommand{\rond}[1]{\build#1_{}^{\>\circ}}
\newcommand{\build}[3]{\mathrel{\mathop{\kern 0pt#1}\limits_{#2}^{#3}}}
\long\def\build#1_#2^#3{\mathrel{\mathop{\kern 0pt#1}\limits_{#2}^{#3}}}

\global\long\def\eclaire{\mathbb}
\global\def\eclaire{\mathbb}
\protected\def\eclaire{\mathbb}

  \newcommand{\eclaire}{\mathbb}
```

Remarks:

- `\def` is mapped to `\newcommand*` and `\long\def` is mapped to `\newcommand`.
- If `\global`, `\protected`, or `\outer` can be detected, the definition remains
  unchanged.
- Only an empty parameter text (`\def\foo{...}`) or undelimited arguments
  (`\def\foo#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9{...}`) are supported. `\newcommand` does not support arbitrary parameter texts (`\def\foo bar{...}`) and delimited arguments (`\def\foo[#1]{...}`).
- Some support for white space after command names (`\def \foo {...}`).
- If `\expandafter` is detected, the definition remains unchanged.
  (Example: `\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def\generatecmd{foo}{...}`)
- Of course, `\newcommand` throws an error, if the command is already defined.
  This requires manual intervention, because different resolutions exist:

  - The command name can be changed to avoid the name clash.
  - If the overwrite is on purpose, `\renewcommand` resolves the issue.